# VBA paste range with dynamic selection

Tags: excel, dynamic, range, copy-paste, vba

I read multiple Q&A's, however it's difficult for me to really understand all the long scripts with the usage of different objects.

I am trying to select a range from one worksheet to an other.
I want to keep the range dynamic, because the range can vary every time. By doing so I have used the following script:

```
Dim range As Long

For range = ActiveCell To ActiveCell.End(xlDown)
Sheets("Stock Report").range("A4" & range).Value = 
    Sheets("Unique File").range("Y8" & range).Value
```

However it doesn't do anything.

This script does work, but I would like to keep the last cell dynamic:

```
Sheets("Stock Report").Range("A4:A9000").Value = 
    Sheets("Unique File").Range("Y8:Y90004").Value
```

I have to do this for multiple columns which are calculated by using other files in a different worksheets and need to sort them finally without all the calculations in an other one.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK try.

```
Sheets("Unique File").Range("Y8:Y" & Sheets("Unique File").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row + 4).Copy
Sheets("Stock Report").Range("A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row gets the last row of the data on the Stock Report sheet and is used to copy down to the same row on the Unique File sheet.  I added 4 because your range starts on 8 on the Unique File sheet.

I think your code didn't work because you were trying to use the "range" you created from the Stock Report sheet on the Unique values sheet.

Comment: Hi Gordon. The thing is that I do not want to select the whole column. It should always start from cells(4, xx). And the range that I want to select do have values. The thing that I do not want is to have more rows at the end than the values I have.